# How do I extract 32-bit audio fingerprint with C# using philips robust hashing algorithm?

Tags: c#, audio-fingerprinting

I'm new to Audio Fingerprint Extraction. I need help to implement Philips Robust Hashing (PRH) Algorithm by C#. It was published as "A Highly Robust Audio Fingerprinting System" by Haitsma et al. But I do not fully understand the steps to extract 32-bit fingerprints. I just need implementations and hope for your valuable guidance and suggestions. Thanks a lot!

Comment: add what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

OpenFG has an algoritme that seems to do the same as "Philips Robust Hashing" (or is the same). It's written in C.
See http://open-fp.sourceforge.net/

I've written an c# implementation that is based on OpenFG. It produces a 32 bit number for about every 371 ms of audio data.
It can reliably detect the right audio file with only 12 to 15 seconds of audio in a database of more than 7 million audio fingerprints.
See https://github.com/nelemans1971/AudioFingerprinting